# str.split() works for '\\' but not '\n' or '\\n'

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have some address data (a columns in a dataframe) that looks like:

```
address
FowlerWhiteBurnettPA\n1395BrickellAvenue\nFourteenthFloor\nMiami,FL33131
Levine&GlassmanLLC\n1655NCommerceParkway\nWeston,FL33326
SimonTrialFirm\nBiscayneBankTower\n2601SouthBayshoreDriveSuite1010\nMiami,FL33133
```

I want to split this columns in order to keep only the firm name. That is, I want to have only:

```
firm
FowlerWhiteBurnettPA
Levine&GlassmanLLC
SimonTrialFirm
```

The code I use is:

```
data['firm'] = data['address'].str.split('\n').str[0]
```

However, this just returns the original address without changing anything. Then I tried

```
data['firm'] = data['address'].str.split('\\').str[0]
```

It splits on '\' and gives me what I want. However, I don't know why '\n' doesn't work.. I also tried to split on '\n' which also doesn't work.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `df.address.values`. Your output probably is :

```
array(['FowlerWhiteBurnettPA\\n1395BrickellAvenue\\nFourteenthFloor\\nMiam....
```

Notice those `\\n` in the string.

If that is the case, you need double escapes on `\` or denote raw_string `r'...'` and single escape for `\` as follows:

```
df.address.str.split('\\\\n').str[0]
```

or

```
df.address.str.split(r'\\n').str[0]

Out[147]:
0    FowlerWhiteBurnettPA
1      Levine&GlassmanLLC
2          SimonTrialFirm
Name: address, dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, the entries look exactly like what you said! This works perfectly - thank you so much for the big help!

Comment: @Tian: Glad I could help